# Deadbolt 2 and role hierarchy feature

Tags: playframework, deadbolt

I am relatively new to **Scala** and **Playframework**.

I would like to know wether **Deadbolt 2** has or plans to have any support for **role hierarchy feature** such as what can be found in the Spring security framework (see below for an example)?

```
<bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF
            ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is a good idea.  I'll take a look at adding support when I have some free time.

Comment: Hello Steve. Great to hear that!